# Power Apps Sees A SQL Item That's Not There

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

In PowerApps, I'm checking to see if a "BookCode" is in SQL (Column: 'Book Number').

```
     Not(IsBlank(Filter(BookDatabase,ThisItem.BookCode='Book Number')))
```

However, **PowerApps is seeing an item that isn't in SQL(?)**

In the image below, blue is my PowerApps Gallery, 'true' is a label with the formula above, and the white square is the SQL DB (BookDatabase) sorted by 'Book number'.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Filter function does not return a *blank* table for that value - it returns an *empty* table, but it is not blank.

You can update your expression to either of those:

```
Not(IsEmpty(Filter(BookDatabase, ThisItem.BookCode = 'Book Number')))
```

or

```
Not(IsBlank(LookUp(BookDatabase, ThisItem.BookCode = 'Book Number')))
```

Since the LookUp function returns a blank record if none is found.

Comment: That's PERFECT Carlos.  Thank you for the additional explanation.  This helped me learn something useful going forward and not just the fix to this one problem!